# OpenERP Jasper Reports

Tags: odoo

After giving up on Syleam's openerp jasper module, I am struggling with Nan Tic's jasper_reports module.

It keeps giving me an error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 6.1\Source\openerp-6.1-latest\openerp-6.1-20121113-003313\openerp\addons\jasper_reports\jasper_report.py", line 39, in <module>

from JasperReports import *

ImportError: No module named JasperReports
```

I am assuming it is looking for a java library of this name. I downloaded all files under java folder and also set the CLASSPATH.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify how you have installed this module??

Comment: i already had iReports 4.7.1 and JasperServer CP 4.7.0 installed. Then I went to the launchpad site for jasper_reports and from the 6.1 branch, downloaded all files (one by one because bazaar kept giving errors). I placed these in the addons folder and updated modules list in openerp. Then i tried to install from the openerp modules list interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you either don't have all the files, or you don't have them in the right place.  Looking at the code repository I see several folders, one of which is JasperReports.  That seems to be what is missing from your installation.

From [the web page](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jasper-reports-commiters/openobject-jasper-reports/jasper-reports-6.1/files/head:/jasper_reports/):

```
-- jasper_reports
 |
 +-- custom_reports
 |
 +-- demo
 |
 +-- doc
 |
 +-- i18n
 |
 +-- JasperReports
 | |
 | |-- __init__.py
 | |
 | |-- AbstractDataGenerator.py
 | |
 | |-- BrowseDataGenerator.py
 | |
 | |-- JasperReport.py
 | |
 | |-- JasperServer.py
 | |
 | |-- RecordDataGenerator.py
 |
 +-- java
 |
 +-- report
 |
 +-- security
 |
 +-- wizard
 |
 |-- __init__.py
 |
 |-- __openerp__.py
 |
 |-- http_server.py
 |
 |-- jasper_demo.xml
 |
 |-- jasper_report.py
 |
 |-- jasper_wizard.xml
 |
 |-- report_xml.py
 |
 |-- report_xml_view.xml
```

As you can see, the fifth folder down is `JasperReports`, and that is what seems to be missing from your installation.

Comment: Guess what! The folder name was the issue! Mine was jasperReports. When I renamed to JasperReports, it worked! Strange, but thanks for taking the time. Now for the next challenge.

Comment: @RazaAli: Your welcome!  Python is case sensitive, so keep that in mind if you ever have to do that again manually.